# how to run rviz in raspian on raspberry pi 4

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, arduino#ros#raspberry, 3dcamera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have installed ros melodic  in raspian on raspberry pi 4 reference link https://wiki.ros.org/ROSberryPi/Installing%20ROS%20Melodic%20on%20the%20Raspberry%20Pi
I have tried trying running $rviz and getting error #command not found, I have sourced the file even though isn't working

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/381545/how-to-run-rviz-in-raspian-on-raspberry-pi-4/) by [Madhankumar26291](https://answers.ros.org/users/76969/madhankumar26291/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2021-07-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [photon](https://answers.ros.org/users/28317/photon/) on 2021-07-03**:
Are you using the ROS-Comm version or the Desktop version? The ROS-Comm version does not contain any GUI tools such as Rviz.

**Comment by [Madhankumar26291](https://answers.ros.org/users/76969/madhankumar26291/) on 2021-07-03**:
I am using ros common version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As the GUI tools would not be installed in the `ROS-Comm` version, therefore tools such as `Rviz` & `rqt` would not be available. Install the `Desktop` version instead.

---

Originally posted by [photon](https://answers.ros.org/users/28317/photon/) with karma: 68 on 2021-07-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Madhankumar26291](https://answers.ros.org/users/76969/madhankumar26291/) on 2021-07-03**:
I am using ubuntu on raspberry pi and its ram is 2gb full desktop it can't handle so i used ros common version

**Comment by [photon](https://answers.ros.org/users/28317/photon/) on 2021-07-03**:
Another way to is to use another ROS installed computer that is connected within the same network, and visualize the topics from there instead of on the RPi itself. You can checkout on how to connect them together here: http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/MultipleMachines